# Criteria for receiving Iron Banner Weapons?

Tags: destiny

I have been hooked on Destiny for a while now, and Iron Banner is one of the things I look forward to competing in the most. I have never been able to get a Iron Banner-specific weapon, but on Thursday, I was rewarded with [Felwinter's Lie](http://www.destinydb.com/items/160095218-felwinters-lie).

I do not know what I did to receive the shotgun, so i want to know if there a certain criteria I must meet to receive Iron Banner Weapons. If not, then is it just completely random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule with Destiny is: if you're not sure why you got something, then you got it by chance.

This applies to Iron Banner as well. The only fixed rewards are those that Lord Saladin sells (he has different limited stock each event). After match rewards are random.

Answer (score 0):

The shotgun was not available for purchase this week (it has been in the past) from the Iron Banner vendor (Lord Saladin).

However, with this expansion Bungie increased the drop rates of legendaries in PvP. The Iron Banner loot table includes the Iron Banner weapons. As a result at the end of a match you randomly received the shotgun Felwinter's Lie.

It is a good weapon. Prior to the expansion, Lord Saladin would offer to reroll Iron Banner weaponry. The ability to reroll the Iron Banner weapons is now also available from the gunsmith. So you can take your shotgun and roll it a few times to try to get some of the desired perks. Keep in mind that they are going to be the old set (and not the new ones), and also that the weapon will still require old materials to upgrade.